# How to use password_hash for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am studying the `CodeIgniter framework` and trying to build a login and registration system. In the bottom are two functions in the controllers for login and registration.

People suggest me using `"'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options),"` instead of `MD5 for password`. I tried to do that but not works.

Can you guys help me with this? Do I need change anything else in my model or view? Thank you guys very much

Controllers: Login function

```
if($this->input->post('loginSubmit')){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $con['returnType'] = 'single';
            $con['conditions'] = array(
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
                'status' => '1'
            );

            $checkLogin = $this->user->getRows($con);
            if($checkLogin){
                $this->session->set_userdata('isUserLoggedIn',TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('userId',$checkLogin['id']);
                redirect('users/account');
            }else{
                $data['error_msg'] = 'Wrong email or password, please try again.';
            }
        }
    }
```

registration function

```
$data = array();
    $userData = array();

    if($this->input->post('regisSubmit')){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|callback_email_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');

        $userData = array(
            'name' => strip_tags($this->input->post('name')),
            'email' => strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'phone' => strip_tags($this->input->post('phone'))
        );

        if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
            $insert = $this->user->insert($userData);
            if($insert){


                $this->session->set_userdata('email',$userData['email']);
                redirect('email');
            }else{
                $data['error_msg'] = 'Some problems occured, please try again.';
            }
```

And here is my getRows function in the models.

```
    function getRows($params = array()){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->userTbl);


    //fetch data by conditions
    if(array_key_exists("conditions",$params)){
        foreach ($params['conditions'] as $key => $value) {
            $this->db->where($key,$value);
        }
    }

    if(array_key_exists("id",$params)){
        $this->db->where('id',$params['id']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->row_array();
    }else{
        //set start and limit
        if(array_key_exists("start",$params) && array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
            $this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
        }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$params) && array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
            $this->db->limit($params['limit']);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if(array_key_exists("returnType",$params) && $params['returnType'] == 'count'){
            $result = $query->num_rows();
        }elseif(array_key_exists("returnType",$params) && $params['returnType'] == 'single'){
            $result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->row_array():FALSE;
        }else{
            $result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
        }
    }

    //return fetched data
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: You need to read up on this. The $Options part was for the memory cost. https://devdocs.io/php/function.password-hash , https://devdocs.io/php/function.password-verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

in registration : *hash password during registration like this with : `password_hash`*

```
$userData = array(
        'name' => strip_tags($this->input->post('name')),
        'email' => strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
        'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'),PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
        'phone' => strip_tags($this->input->post('phone'))
    );
```

In login : *check password using `password_verify` in login*

```
/*get the user data based on email or whatever your condition is but exclude password here*/

/* your condition here 
$con['email'] = $email;
$con['status'] = 1; or whatever you set in $con
*/
$checkLogin = $this->user->getRows($con);
if($checkLogin)
{
    if (password_verify($password,$checkLogin['password']))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('isUserLoggedIn',TRUE);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userId',$checkLogin['id']);
        redirect('users/account');
    }

}
else
{
     $data['error_msg'] = 'Wrong email or password, please try again.';
}
```

Your model's method `getRows()` should be like this :

```
public function getRows($where = array())
{
    if (! empty($where))
    {
       $this->db->where($where);
       $query = $this->db->get('users');
       if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
       {
          return $query->row_array();
       } 
     }
     else
     {
         $query = $this->db->get('users');
         if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
         {
            return $query->result_array();
         } 
     }
}
```

for more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! Now the registration is working really good now but I keep failing when I log in(I think probably is the model's problem?). I uploaded me getRows function in model's method. Could you have a look and tell me where is wrong? Thank you very much

Comment: oh dear, why don't you keep it simple just look at the getRows() method in my answer,

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a model method named `getRows()` if it returns `row_array()` -- it would make more sense to call it `getRow()` in this case.  And why limit the number of rows returned if there are where conditions? What if there is a where condition and multiple rows are desired?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `password_hash()` function in CodeIgniter. [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

```
// create a function custom_password_hash()
private function custom_password_hash($pass){
   return password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
}
```

Now you can call this from anywhere within the same Controller as:

```
$userData = array(
            'name' => strip_tags($this->input->post('name')),
            'email' => strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
            'password' =>$this->custom_password_hash($this->input->post('password')),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'phone' => strip_tags($this->input->post('phone'))
        );
```

Hope this will make sense for you.

Comment: `strip_tags()` _can be_ damaging to a valid email address.  You can validate this value if you like, but I do not recommend sanitizing it.  I don't think I would sanitize the name or phone either.  You will be html encoding this string EVERY TIME you print it into an html document anyhow.  The phone number can probably have very strict validation to begin with -- which tags would never survive.

Answer (score 0):

`md5()` to `password_hash()` for better password encryption.

In register controller:

**Change:**

```
'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
```

**To:**

```
'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'),PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
```

In login controller - removed password as condition for `$this->user->getRows(..)` and subsequently added `password_verify()` to login check.

Make sure `$checkLogin['password']` is also returned from `$this->user->getRows($con)` for `password_verify(..)` to work.

**Updated Code:**

```
if($this->input->post('loginSubmit')){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $con['returnType'] = 'single';
            $con['conditions'] = array(
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'status' => '1'
            );

            $checkLogin = $this->user->getRows($con); // assumes 'password' field is also returned..
            if(password_verify($this->input->post('password'), $checkLogin['password']){
                $this->session->set_userdata('isUserLoggedIn',TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('userId',$checkLogin['id']);
                redirect('users/account');
            }else{
                $data['error_msg'] = 'Wrong email or password, please try again.';
            }
        }
    }
```